# Best practice for error handling anon functions

Tags: go

I'm working on some large Go projects but I wanted to ask a question about best practice on error handling. As far as I'm aware errors shouldn't be hidden / "caught" but I could be wrong.

In a lot of the projects I'm working on I'm seeing a lot of this in http handlers. Sometimes with about 8 function calls

```
func FooHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := func() error {
        var1, err := doSomething1()
        if err != nil {
             return fmt.Error("some error")
        }

        var2, err := doSomething2()
        if err != nil {
             return fmt.Error("some error")
        }

        var3, err := doSomething3()
        if err != nil {
             return fmt.Error("some error")
        }

        var4, err := doSomething4()
        if err != nil {
             return fmt.Error("some error")
        }
    }(); err != nil {
        // build error response here
    }
    // do successful response here
}
```

This seems like doing try / catch in Go, but it would be good to know if this is accepted practice or not. The alternative would be `if err != nil` then using a function to write the error response, but would be repeating code.

Comment: Anon function might be a little hard to read, making it regular seems a better choice. You can just write a non-anon function (the regular one) that does the job and returns an error, and in the actual handler function, you "catch" the return error and handle it. I think it is pretty common practice in many code base, including some part of standard library.

Comment: Specific to the situation you're in, my suggestion would be to have the handlers return an error directly and, upon registering, wrap them into something that satisfies `http.Handler/HandlerFunc` and handles the error. e.g. https://play.golang.org/p/nsdOMRrf8VK

Comment: @leafbebob thanks for the comment. That's good to know, coming from an OOP background, I'd tend to abstract this somewhere, but I suppose it does add complication too.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for the comment. I really like this method of handling the errors. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a bad question at all, but it isn't a good fit for stackoverflow. No-one can say if this is "accepted practice", only if they like it or not. Stackoverflow guidelines suggest questions should have clear right/wrong answers. Maybe the software engineering stack exchange site is a better place for it (or even the go discussion groups like golang-nuts).

Comment: Thanks @PaulHankin. Will bear that in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above approach is completely fine and not "catching" anything in the sense of `try .. catch` as other languages would do.

The main reason for the anonymous function is to write the error specific response only once. There are other ways to do it if you don't like that approach.

### handle error function

For example you could have a function to handle / return the error so this code does not clutter the handler:

```golang
func handleErr(w http.ResponseWriter, err error, statusCode int) {
    log.Printf("statusCode: %d; error: %s", statusCode, err)

    w.WriteHeader(statusCode)

    bts, err := json.Marshal(struct {
        Error string
    }{
        Error: err.Error(),
    })
    if err != nil {
        _, _ = w.Write([]byte(`{"Error":"error while marshalling error response"`))
    }

    _, _ = w.Write(bts)
}
```

A handler would then look like this:

```golang
func FooHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var1, err := doSomething1()
    if err != nil {
        handleErr(w, err, http.StatusBadRequest, "some user error msg")
        return
    }

    var2, err := doSomething2()
    if err != nil {
        handleErr(w, err, http.StatusUnauthorized, "some user error msg")
        return
    }

    var3, err := doSomething3()
    if err != nil {
        handleErr(w, err, http.StatusInternalServerError, "some user error msg")
        return
    }

    var4, err := doSomething4()
    if err != nil {
        handleErr(w, err, http.StatusInternalServerError, "some user error msg")
        return
    }

    // do successful response here
}
```

## using a middleware

As @mkopriva suggested in the comments, you can also use a wrapper for the handlers:

```golang
func handleErr(f func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (int, error)) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        statusCode, err := f(w, r)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }

        log.Printf("statusCode: %d; error: %s", statusCode, err)

        w.WriteHeader(statusCode)

        bts, err := json.Marshal(struct {
            Error string
        }{
            Error: err.Error(),
        })
        if err != nil {
            _, _ = w.Write([]byte(`{"Error":"error while marshalling error response"`))
        }

        _, _ = w.Write(bts)
    }
}
```

It will get wrapped when registering the handler:

```golang
http.Handle("/foo", handleErr(FooHandler))
```

The `FooHandler` can now return statusCode and error:

```golang
func FooHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (int, error) {
    var1, err := doSomething1()
    if err != nil {
        return http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Error("some error")
    }

    var2, err := doSomething2()
    if err != nil {
        return http.StatusUnauthorized, fmt.Error("some error")
    }

    var3, err := doSomething3()
    if err != nil {
        return http.StatusInternalServerError, fmt.Error("some error")
    }

    var4, err := doSomething4()
    if err != nil {
        return http.StatusInternalServerError, fmt.Error("some error")
    }

    // do successful response here
    return http.StatusOK, nil
}
```